# Half Google Map visible in Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I have two fragment in my activity. First one is showing list of items and second fragment is showing google map. When I tap on google map tab, Google Map is visible but only in half area. In first half map is visible but second half only black part. While its covering complete area. When I touch and fling black area my map also fling. It means black area also part of Map.

And this issue is not in all phones. Its only in few phones like lenovo. I also check same map implementation in a activity only(not using fragment) and its working fine.

Have a look on screenshot.
[image: Google Map Fragment]

I also found one thing that when I tap on search box, my map start showing properly.

[image: Google Map Fragment Right One]

Have a look on fragment_map.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context="mypackageName.MyActivity">

        <data>

            <import type="android.view.View" />

            <variable
                name="viewModel"
                type="mypackage.map.googlemap.GViewModel" />
        </data>
      <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/_600DP">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    </layout>
```

Comment: share xml file code.

Comment: I add my fragment_map.xml file. Do I also need to upload activity layout file? I am using a ViewPager in my activity to show map and on dropdown menu selection ,show list.

Comment: it looks like "keyboard is opened". check your manifest about "open keyboard when activity started" and try to `clearFocus()` on your search before you start showing your map.

Comment: I add clear focus on onResume method of Fragment, but its still not working

Comment: I didn't find any solution for this problem but I change my fragment implementation. Before I were using ViewPager + Fragment but now I am using FragmentManager to replace my fragment and this problem not exist. I know this is very strange but to make module workable for all phone, I have to do this.